# Is it possible to getX() with getClic()?

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

i tried this and it causes me a nullpointerexception when i try to access getX(), why ??
b is my GUI : http://pastebin.com/8J4uA1ny (if you need something more tell me in the comments i'll add it, fanks)

```
MouseEvent m = b.getClic();
xMouse = m.getX();
yMouse = m.getY();
System.out.println("xMouse : "+xMouse+"  | yMouse : "+yMouse);
```

thanks for help mates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code (

```
    if(this.clics.isEmpty())
        return null;
    else 
        return this.clics.remove(0);
```

Since you only add something to *clics* when there actually is a clic**k** we can assume it's the first condition the one that's causing your problems.

Since you are considering the posibility of your array having no events, you should add a condition like:

```
MouseEvent m = b.getClic();
if (m != null) {
    xMouse = m.getX();
    yMouse = m.getY();
    System.out.println("xMouse : "+xMouse+"  | yMouse : "+yMouse);
}
```

Comment: ah yea thanks ! (and it's written "clic" without a 'k' because it's in french lel sry) i tried to to this but with a "if (m.getX() != null)" but it was impossible to test if an int was null
thx

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer exception show that your "m" object is not instanciate correcly (probably is null). Are you sure that the "b.getClic();" return something ?